# Sync gmail using mbsync (isync) on debian linux using XOAUTH2

Tags: email, imap, offlineimap

I am trying to sync my mails from gmail to my local mail server using [mbsync](http://isync.sourceforge.net/mbsync.html). But i keep getting an error `Error: SASL(-4): no mechanism available: No worthy mechs found`

Here is my `.mbsyncrc` file:

```
#IMAP server you wish to copy mails from.
IMAPAccount original
Host imap.gmail.com
User username@gmail.com
AuthMechs XOAUTH2
Pass access_token_recieved_from_google
UseIMAPS yes
CertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

# The IMAP server you wish to copy mails to.
IMAPAccount target
Host local.mail.server.host
User local_user
Pass  somepass
AuthMechs LOGIN
UseIMAPS yes
CertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

# Link IMAP server to remote used below. Note Account is set to     'original' now -- we'll be set it to 'target' later!
IMAPStore my-remote
Account original

# The local storage we'll be using. Note the trailing slash at the end of the Path!
MaildirStore my-local
Path ~/mail/
Inbox ~/mail/INBOX/

# This is where the magic happens. Note Sync is set to 'Pull' now -- we'll     set it to 'Push' later!
Channel my-channel
Master :my-remote:
Slave :my-local:
Patterns *
Create Both
Sync Pull
SyncState *
```

system: `Linux stretch 4.9.0-7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-1 (2018-07-05) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

mbsync --version `isync 1.2.1`

looks like mbsync isn't recognizing `XOAUTH2` for keyword `AuthMechs`. If i change the AuthMech type to `LOGIN`, i get an `invalid credentials` error. (makes sense, i put in an auth token in place of the password).

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://blog.onodera.asia/2020/06/how-to-use-google-g-suite-oauth2-with.html ?